# Center embedded iframe in div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am working on developing a simple webpage for my small business and am running into a small issue. I have a page called "Find Us" that visitors can go to and view two embedded iframes from Google Maps, one is the map view and one is the street view. I created a row and column class in my CSS file so that I can have them set side by side. This is working, but my question is how do I get the iframes to be centered inside of their respective row divs? I've tried setting text-align:center in the row and column to no avail, and when I inspect the page in Firefox it appears that the iframe is actually inside a couple of divs that are created at runtime that are inside the column div I created (which is why I assume the text-align:center change in column had no effect). I've tried quite a bit and am a bit of a novice at HTML and CSS so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the relevant code that I've got:

HTML:

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d820.109972365762!2d-82.9747956!3d34.6940833!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8858f48d9c0b5b95%3A0x9025d413ee9c3690!2sComputers%20Plus!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1600897132491!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;display:block;float:left;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" class="card"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1600897261750!6m8!1m7!1s3ZaVoRt_4ZAZOf7ojip-rQ!2m2!1d34.69359001695453!2d-82.97439599257413!3f329.63553875594886!4f-3.155410164097759!5f1.6853925263716625" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;display:block;float:left;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" class="card"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 6px 6px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

The code for the iframes is unchanged from what Google Maps provided. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by removing `float:left` from the `style` attribute of the `<iframe>` elements, which is currently preventing them from being centered.

Comment: I figured this out literally 30 seconds before seeing your answer, I was logging back in to answer my own question lol Thank you so much though, you are absolutely correct. I removed the float:left and added margin:auto instead and it centered them inside of their respective divs. Thanks again!